# How does the absence of a pivot in a given column make a variable 'free'?

Tags: linear-algebra

Why is it that, if a given variable does not have a pivot variable within the column of a given REF / RREF matrix, it can be arbitrarily chosen?

Answer (score 0):

When you rewrite the rref matrix in equation form, you backsolve. Any row that contains a pivot element gives you a dependent variable, for example:
$$x_1 + 2x_2 - x_3 = 4$$
$$3x_3 = 2$$
The variable $x_2$ is a free variable, and $x_1$ and $x_3$ are pivot variables. Basically, there is no equation that starts with a multiple of $x_2$, so it is impossible to solve for it. Rather, we can solve for $x_1$ in terms of $x_2$ and $x_3$, so $x_2$ is free.

Comment: Couldn't we for solve $x_2$ in terms of $x_1$ and $x_3$ and call it a pivot variable?